# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:org.apache.maven.plugins

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins

environment: 
Eclipse 4.4.2
Tomcat : 7
java 1.7
maven 3.5
STS packages installed.

This is my condition right now. when I made Spring legacy project(MVC) there was some problem in pom.xml.

First of all, Error occurred in war  but after I clean the maven and update, the error was gone. but after that, the part of  occurred the error. I don't know how to fix it.

But strangely I did this just like same on my other laptop yesterday, There wasn't any problem.

```
CentOS7
java 1.8
Eclipse 4.7.0
Tomcat 8.5.16
```

Here is the section of pom file

```
<plugin>                 
//plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin2.5.1:testCompile(execution:default-testComplile, phase:test-conpile)").

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Take a look at [Life cycles](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_build_life_cycle.htm). Should help you.

Comment: First can you show the full pom.xml file? Furthermore you are defining very old plugin versions....better use most recent versions which can be found here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: after I changed, it worked! thanks ever so:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the plugins in one of the life-cycles as pointed out by the error. If you want these plugins to be packed in the war file then enclose them in the `<packaging></packaging>`. But you will be needed to include that in a life cycle.

Comment: If you think that my answer helped you in solving your problem then you can mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Once done , try doing a Update Project by Right Click Project , Maven->Update Maven Project and select codebase and do check the Force Update of Snapshot/Release check box.
This will update your maven build and will surely remove your errors with pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

Posting my solution, in case anyone else runs into a similar error. I had a very similar issue on a much later version of Eclipse, etc.  No amount of Maven>Update Project solved it.

I ran manually ran "mvn clean install" from the command line, and it cleaned up the errors in eclipse.

- Eclipse Neon
- maven-compiler-plugin 3.8.1